# How to format and send command for printing bill items on termal printer Datecs LP-50 H?

Tags: c#, wpf, printing, serial-port, thermal-printer

My printer is connected via Serial Port (COM3, 9600), and now I want to print some text on it. I have tried all codes that I was found on net, mostly named for epson printers, but none of them didn't worked for me.

Simply I want to send message to printer on Button_click event.

```
 private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!serialPort.IsOpen)
            serialPort.Open();
        serialPort.Write(Message());
    }
```

Simple test message would be (and that's where I need help):

```
private String Message() {
    char[] init = new char[] { (char)0x1b, '@' };
    String msg = "";
    foreach (char c in init)
        msg += c;

       msg+="Hello World";
    return msg;
}
```

I also have user manual for printer, with pseudo command:

```
LPRINT “0123456789012345678901”; 
LPRINT CHR$ (&HA); 
LPRINT CHR$ (&H9) + “AAA”; 
LPRINT CHR$ (&H9) + “BBB”; 
LPRINT CHR$ (&HA); 
LPRINT CHR$ (&H1B) + “D”; 
LPRINT CHR$ (3) + CHR$ (7) + CHR$ (14) + CHR$ (0); 
LPRINT CHR$ (&H9) + “AAA”; 
LPRINT CHR$ (&H9) + “BBB”; 
LPRINT CHR$ (&H9) + “CCC” + CHR$ (&HA);
```

How this would be converted to C# and does something missing in this pseudo command? I need help here to properly define my Message() method and to print text.

Comment: Dips are: Sw1: ON, Sw2: ON, Sw3: OFF ?, try to send only 07H (a beep) to check if your serial connection is okay.

Comment: I'm not sure anymore what is proper way to send "beep" command, also. But, I was installed some software that came with printer, and that program successfully connects to printer, and prints diagnostic data. 
So, everything is working and is connected properly. Problem is just to correctly formate and send command to Serial Port.

Comment: Format should be no problem. Just send a message like serialPort.WriteLine("Hello World"); To send your beep do it with serialPort.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(new byte[] { 0x07 })); If the connecton is okay, this should work. If not its a connection problem. Check the datasheet for parity, start- stopbits, DTR ,.... and setup your serialPort like needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was found workaround for my problem. Datecs have windows drivers for this type of printer, so that printer acts as regular printer. No messing with com ports and it's params, just send regular formated string for printing. Here is methodt for printing String

```
public void PrintText(StringBuilder s, String PrinterName)
    {
        PrintDocument p = new PrintDocument();
        p.PrintPage += delegate(object sender1, PrintPageEventArgs e1)
        {
            e1.Graphics.DrawString(s.ToString(), new Font("Times New Roman", 11), new SolidBrush(System.Drawing.Color.Black), new RectangleF(0, 0, p.DefaultPageSettings.PrintableArea.Width, p.DefaultPageSettings.PrintableArea.Height));

        };
        try
        {
            p.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = PrinterName;
            p.Print();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Exception Occured While Printing", ex);
        }
    }
```

For this method is needed to add references:

```
System.Drawing
```

And to add using statment on top

```
using System.Drawing;
```

Comment: Thanks mate. For anyone who doesn't want to use plain text but wants to use LP-50 commands, checkout my implentation

https://github.com/kosgeinsky/thermal-client-lp50/blob/master/thermal-printer-client/ThermalPrinterBridge.cs